# How to implement a login screen with routing

Tags: routes, sapui5

Im using the router to navigate between views. But i have trouble to implement the login screen.

How can i tell the router to redirect to the login screen if there is no authenication made by the user?

i configured the router in the component.js

Comment: I need some background: on what stack have you deployed your application (e.g. ABAP, etc. )?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a callback to the router which is called if a route has matched. In the callback you can check if the matched route requires a login and forward to the login view.